# React Context doesnt Save global state Typescript from childcomponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router, react-context

trying to use react context to save a userStatus context globally

code is as follows:

app.tsx

```
function App() {
  const [userStatus, setUserStatus] = React.useState(UserStatus.LoggedOff);
  console.log("userStatus is " + userStatus);

  return (
    <UserStatusContext.Provider value={{ userStatus, setUserStatus }}>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Ping Messenger</h1>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Hub />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </UserStatusContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

context.tsx

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export enum UserStatus {
  LoggedIn = 0,
  LoggedOff = 1,
}

export type UserStatusContextType = {
  userStatus: UserStatus;
  setUserStatus: (userStatus: UserStatus) => void;
};

export const UserStatusContext = createContext<UserStatusContextType>({
  userStatus: UserStatus.LoggedOff,
  setUserStatus: (userStatus) => console.warn("log on status unknown"),
});

export const useUserStatus = () => useContext(UserStatusContext);
```

and my loginPage.tsx

```
const LoginPage = () => {
...
 const { userStatus, setUserStatus } = useUserStatus();


    var loginSuccess = await authService.login(credentials);

    if (loginSuccess) {
      setUserStatus(UserStatus.LoggedIn);
   }
...
```

now, when I console log around, in my app.tsx file,
console.log("userStatus is " + userStatus);

when navigating to '/login' it logs 'userStatus is 0'

when submitting the form  it briefly logs  'userStatus is 1' (this is the desired output) but when the page compltes / refreshing or i navigate to '/'  it log 'userStatus is 0'. it doesnt appear to be saving and persisting the state.

any ideas?

Comment: How exactly do you navigate? When you refresh a page you definitely lose state in App.

Comment: Not sure if this is causing a problem here, but I think you should move the Router component out of the App component (move Router component to top-level and make App component children of Router).

Comment: how would you persist state then?

Comment: How are you navigating around the app? If you aren't using `react-router` to do it, i.e. like if you are manually editing the URL in the address bar, this is likely reloading the page and remounting the entire app. Can you include a more complete [mcve] and more clearly explain exactly what you are doing to produce the issue?

Comment: i am manually manipulating the url

Comment: Ok, so if you use RRD `Link` or `Navigate` components or the `navigate` function does it all work like you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are manually editing the URL in the browser's address bar this is reloading the page, which reloads the React app, e.g. remounts the entire app. All React state resides only in memory, so when the app remounts all state is reset.

This is an issue of state persistence, i.e. persisting the `userStatus` state *through* page reloads. For this you could persist/initialize `userStatus` to/from localStorage.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [userStatus, setUserStatus] = React.useState(
    // initial value from localStorage or default value
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userStatus")) ?? UserStatus.LoggedOff
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("userStatus is " + userStatus);
    // persist userStatus state changes to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("userStatus", JSON.stringify(userStatus));
  }, [userStatus]);
  
  return (
    <UserStatusContext.Provider value={{ userStatus, setUserStatus }}>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Ping Messenger</h1>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Hub />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </UserStatusContext.Provider>
  );
}
```